# Filtering objects based on many-to-many field in current object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a drinks recipe app I'm building that has tags in a many-to-many field that are part of each drink. The tags are a basic taste description.
I now want to display 3 similar drinks based on the tag of the current drink.

My view looks like this:

```
def drinkdetail_view(request, slug=None):
    #Grab the correct drink
    try:
        obj = DrinkRecipe.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except:
        obj = None
    if obj is  None:
        return HttpResponse("Not found.")
   
context = {
    "drink": obj,
}

return render(request,'drinks/drinkdetail.html', context)
```

The model looks like this:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    drinkTag = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.drinkTag}"

class TagTaste(models.Model):
    drinkTagTaste = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.drinkTagTaste}"
    
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    ingredientRum = models.ForeignKey('Bottle', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    ingredientName = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    ingredientAmount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1,max_digits=5)
    drink = models.ForeignKey('DrinkRecipe', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.ingredientRum:
            return f"{self.ingredientRum}"
        else:
            return f"{self.ingredientName}"


class DrinkRecipe(models.Model):
    drinkTag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    drinkTagRum = models.ForeignKey(Bottle, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    drinkTagTaste = models.ManyToManyField(TagTaste)
    drinkName = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    drinkDescription = HTMLField()
    drinkImage = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_handler)
    drinkActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    imgLocation = 'drinks'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.drinkName}"


    def get_ingredients(self):
        return self.ingredient_set.all()
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse ('rhumSite:drinkDetail', kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
```

How do I filter for `drinkTag` or `drinkTagTaste` in my view based on the current drink?
I've tried:

```
similar_drinks = DrinkRecipe.objects.filter(drinkTag__drinkTag=obj.drinkTag)
```

But that doesnt work. Hardcoding one of the tags works just fine.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
similar_drinks = DrinkRecipe.objects.filter(drinkTag__drinkrecipe=obj)
```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `drink_tag` instead of <s>`drinkTag`</s>.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm.
I'll adjust the field names.